# $f$ is essentially bounded, if and only if $\sup\{\|f\|_p\} < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $f$ a real-valued measurable function. I am trying to show that $f \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ i.e $$\inf\{M \geq 0 : \mu\{x : |f(x)| > M\} = 0\}  < \infty$$ if and only if $f \in \mathcal{L}^{p}$ for all $p  \in [1,\infty)$ and $\sup\{\|f\|_p\} < \infty$

I have been stuck for a while now, trying to work from the definitions, but couldn't get anywhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This cannot be an equivalence, consider $f \equiv1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  finite measure for this. Obviously $f=1$ is in $L^{\infty}$ of the real line but it is not in any $L^{p}$ for $p <\infty$.

Now assume that you have a finite measure. One implication is obvious: if $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere then $\sup_p \int |f|^{p} <\infty$.  Now suppose $\|f\|_p$ is bounded. Suppose $f$ is not esentially bounded. Then, for any positive number $M$ the set $\{x: |f(x)| >M\}$ has positive measure. Let $T$ be the measure of this set. Then $\int |f|^{p} \geq \int |f|^{p} I_{\{x: |f(x)| >M\}} \geq M^{p} T$. Raise both sides to power $1/p$ and take limit to see that $\lim \inf \|f\|_p \geq M$. Since $M$ is arbitrary the proof is complete.